# Create and Invert MultiMap w/ Java 8 Streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream, multimap, flatmap

How can I convert a `Set<Result>` into a `Map<Item, Set<String>>` or `SetMultimap<Item, String>` using Java 8 streams or Multimaps, where `Result` is:

```
class Result {
    String name;
    Set<Item> items;
}
```

For example, I start with:

```
result1:
    name: name1
    items:
        - item1
        - item2
result2:
    name: name2
    items:
        - item2
        - item3
```

and end with:

```
item1:
    - name1
item2:
    - name1
    - name2
item3:
    - name2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

two important methods in code snippet below are [Stream.flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) & [Collectors.mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

results.stream()
    //map Stream<Result> to Stream<Entry<Item>,String>
   .flatMap(it -> it.items.stream().map(item -> new SimpleEntry<>(item, it.name)))
   //group Result.name by Item 
   .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toSet())));
```

Comment: nice! was just gonna say that `.collect(toList()).stream()` is unnecessary but you just edited it. thanks!

Comment: @mathematician yes, I have already removed, you maybe seen the early version code.

Comment: though this errs with `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` for the Entry::get methods?

Comment: @mathematician you must make sure `flatMap` return a `Stream<Map.Entry>`.

Answer (score 2):

Once there is `Collectors.flatMapping` in jdk-9, it could look a little different. Also your `Item` instances need to be comparable in some way, or you can specify that in `groupBy` (let's say by a field 'itemName'):

```
Map<Item, Set<String>> map = results.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.flatMapping(
                    (Result result) -> result.getItems()
                            .stream()
                            .map((Item item) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(item, result.getName())),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Item::getItemName)),
                            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet()))));
```